# Extract Lists from Text File in Elixir

Tags: list, file, elixir

I have a bit of an odd question, but I have read all sorts of Elixir documentation and textbooks in sort of an answer to this and have come up with nothing.

I have a set of .txt files which each contain data in list format. So, the content of the .txt file looks like (brackets included):

```
[a, [a, b], c, [d, e, f], g]
```

If I read this file into an Elixir function, it will be read as a string. And if I use `String.tolist` it will include the brackets as entries in the new list. But is there a way to read this as a list, formatted just like it is in the file? Obviously I could easily write a function that uses Regex to read the data character-by-character, starting a new list each time I find an opening bracket and ending the list each time I find a closing bracket. However, this would be very resource intensive and seems very "un-Elixirian."

Does Elixir have any built-in functions or commands which would recognize the brackets and would format this as a list without having to read the data character-by-character? Or, does anyone smarter than me know of a more efficient way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the text in your files is valid elixir code, then you can use `Code.eval_string` however, unless the strings are quoted in exactly 
Elixir fashion, it likely won't work.

i.e. your example data would have to look like:

```
["a", ["a", "b"], "c", ["d", "e", "f"], "g"]
```

You could build a parser to do all the quoting, but by then you're
already half way to a real parser. The string is going to have to be parsed by something, using the built-in Elixir parser just involves you
writing less code.